# I am slowly going crazy. This must have an easy answer. How do localhost RPC servers tell clients which port they're running on?

Tags: networking, tcp, port, rpc

I have a problem, I'm sure this is a common problem, but I've been Googling for hours and I've found nothing.

1. I have written an RPC server for an application that serves requests over HTTP.
2. It only needs to be accessible from localhost.
3. I run my server on port 0, because I want to avoid port clashes. I receive a dynamic port. The server knows this port.
4. My client connects to... Which port? How does it know???

What does the server need to do to publicise the port?

There must be a simple, standard solution to this. I don't want to hard-code a port since I don't want the user to ever have to touch port settings. Every question I find is telling me to hard-code the port. This seems completely insane for a localhost server. Surely this is a common problem? Surely there's a better way?

What on earth is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: You could use multicast so that the client can query the server for address and port.

Comment: In the old days, we had the [RPC port mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap) that ran on port 111. Local services would register their ports with the local port mapper and if you needed to find a service, you could figure out what port it was bound to by asking the port mapper. Punch "rpcbind" into your favorite search engine to learn more.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This seems like what I'm looking for. What do people use nowadays? I need to know the service will almost certainly be running on the host machine (the environment precludes external dependencies). Is rpcbind still a reliable tool that either will be running, or is startable without root privileges? Is it compatible with an HTTP-based JSON-RPC service, or does it have to be ONC RPC?

Comment: Not many machines still run `rpcbind` these days. It's not needed unless you're using NFS and there have been some security issues in the past. It can't be started without at least the ability to open privileged ports. If this is purely local, why not use a file or named object of some kind to communicate the port number?

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you. I was thinking I might have to use a file, but I wanted to avoid it because it's messy and I'd have to make assumptions about the file system. What kind of named object could I use? Environment variables would be ideal, but they're not available to parent shells. I need some way of accessing the port anywhere in the user's session. I don't mind implementing it separately for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: @JackCC On Linux, you can use `shm_open` to open a named shared memory object. On Windows, you can do something analogous with `CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ...)`.